# How to get all <tr> elements from table using Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

I do not know why I get only one `<tr>` element. I search for my table

```
WebElement tableProducts = driver.findElement(By.id("gridAvailableProducts"));
```

then i want to find all `<tr>` elements

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = tableProducts.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

but when i check tableRows size I get 1. I do not get it because i use this sample code earlier and it works fine.
Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="gridAvailableProducts">
<thead>
<tr id="gridProductsHead">
    <th class="gridImgHeader"></th>
    <th class="gridNameHeader"><a href="#" id="name" class="sortAvailableProducts sortArrowAsc">Product name</a></th>
    <th class="gridIndexHeader"><a href="#" id="productindex" class="sortAvailableProducts">Index</a></th>
    <th class="gridProductPackHeader"><a href="#" id="IDDictUnitOfMeasure" class="sortAvailableProducts">Product pack</a></th>
    <th class="gridNetPriceHeader"><a href="#" id="netprice" class="sortAvailableProducts">Net price</a></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="addProductToyaTr" data-frequency="0/0/0" data-weight="0" data-volume="0" data-account="0" data-mccount="0" data-ibcount="125" data-smallestpackquantity="125" data-unit="PCE" data-pkwiu="" data-price="3.43" data-id="10731" data-index="INDEX_10731">
    <td class="pImg"><a title="Produkt 10731" style="z-index:1000; position:relative;" rel="grp1" class="bigImg" href="/B2B/img/INDEX_10731.jpg">
        <img alt="" width="45" height="45" src="/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg'"></a></td>
    <td class="pName gridProductNameRow">Produkt 10731</td>
    <td class="gridProductIndexRow">INDEX_10731</td>
    <td class="gridProductPackRow">PCE</td>
    <td class="gridProductPriceRow">3.43</td>
    <td><div class="addProductToyaGreen"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="addProductToyaTr" data-frequency="0/0/0" data-weight="0" data-volume="0" data-account="0" data-mccount="0" data-ibcount="125" data-smallestpackquantity="125" data-unit="PCE" data-pkwiu="" data-price="10.36" data-id="10732" data-index="INDEX_10732">
    <td class="pImg"><a title="Produkt 10732" style="z-index:1000; position:relative;" rel="grp1" class="bigImg" href="/B2B/img/INDEX_10732.jpg">
        <img alt="" width="45" height="45" src="/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg'"></a></td>
    <td class="pName gridProductNameRow">Produkt 10732</td><td class="gridProductIndexRow">INDEX_10732</td>
    <td class="gridProductPackRow">PCE</td><td class="gridProductPriceRow">10.36</td>
    <td><div class="addProductToyaGreen"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="addProductToyaTr" data-frequency="0/0/0" data-weight="0" data-volume="0" data-account="0" data-mccount="0" data-ibcount="125" data-smallestpackquantity="125" data-unit="PCE" data-pkwiu="" data-price="8.18" data-id="10733" data-index="INDEX_10733">
    <td class="pImg"><a title="Produkt 10733" style="z-index:1000; position:relative;" rel="grp1" class="bigImg" href="/B2B/img/INDEX_10733.jpg">
        <img alt="" width="45" height="45" src="/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg'"></a></td>
    <td class="pName gridProductNameRow">Produkt 10733</td><td class="gridProductIndexRow">INDEX_10733</td>
    <td class="gridProductPackRow">PCE</td><td class="gridProductPriceRow">8.18</td>
    <td><div class="addProductToyaGreen"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="addProductToyaTr" data-frequency="0/0/0" data-weight="0" data-volume="0" data-account="0" data-mccount="0" data-ibcount="125" data-smallestpackquantity="125" data-unit="PCE" data-pkwiu="" data-price="10.4" data-id="10734" data-index="INDEX_10734">
    <td class="pImg"><a title="Produkt 10734" style="z-index:1000; position:relative;" rel="grp1" class="bigImg" href="/B2B/img/INDEX_10734.jpg">
        <img alt="" width="45" height="45" src="/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg'"></a></td>
    <td class="pName gridProductNameRow">Produkt 10734</td>
    <td class="gridProductIndexRow">INDEX_10734</td>
    <td class="gridProductPackRow">PCE</td>
    <td class="gridProductPriceRow">10.40</td>
    <td><div class="addProductToyaGreen"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="addProductToyaTr" data-frequency="0/0/0" data-weight="0" data-volume="0" data-account="0" data-mccount="0" data-ibcount="125" data-smallestpackquantity="125" data-unit="PCE" data-pkwiu="" data-price="13.66" data-id="10735" data-index="INDEX_10735">
    <td class="pImg"><a title="Produkt 10735" style="z-index:1000; position:relative;" rel="grp1" class="bigImg" href="/B2B/img/INDEX_10735.jpg">
        <img alt="" width="45" height="45" src="/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='/B2B/images/nofoto.jpg'"></a></td>
    <td class="pName gridProductNameRow">Produkt 10735</td><td class="gridProductIndexRow">INDEX_10735</td>
    <td class="gridProductPackRow">PCE</td>
    <td class="gridProductPriceRow">13.66</td>
    <td><div class="addProductToyaGreen"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

When i try to get element by `xpath`

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gridAvailableProducts\"]/tbody/tr[3]"));
```

I get error that

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Comment: your code seems correct, you can take screenshot when it fails to debug it.

Comment: is the table fully populated when this code is run?  Perhaps you need to wait for it to display.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware u are right. For test i sleep thread for 10s and then i get good size :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of sleep thread best way to use `WebDriverWait` with [`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) to wait until nested elements become visible as below :-

```
WebElement tableProducts = driver.findElement(By.id("gridAvailableProducts"));

List<WebElement> tableRows = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy(tableProducts, By.tagName("tr")));
```

Comment: Thanks, I know, but  for fast check i used Thread.sleep() then i moved to WebDriverWait.